# Artemis Fowl's Real Life IQ

Tags: artemis-fowl

What would Artemis's IQ be in real life? What percentile would he fall under?

Answer (score 3):

He would be in the top percentile. Anyone with an IQ over 135 or so is in the top 2%. While they do not mention it specifically in the books as far as I know, it is mentioned that he has the "highest IQ in Europe".

Depending on how you assess it, Goethe was the top mind in Europe and topped out at 210ish, so I would presume to guess that Artemis was a bit higher than that, so 225-250 range. (The top 5 European IQ's in order were Goethe, Einstein, Da Vinci, Maxwell and Newton).

As requested - Meta analysis that estimated IQ by either testing or by achievements in various fields, [Encyclopedia of Human Thermodynamics](http://www.eoht.info/page/IQ%3a+200+?t=anon).

As well as:
[Estimated IQ's](http://hem.bredband.net/b153434/Index.htm)

Most of these come out of a study published in the 1920's by Dr. Catherine Cox where they estimated IQ's of famous people by the age and accomplishments that they showed, and either use the study as a basis or use it as a springboard for their own estimations.

Comment: You need to support your assertions about the IQs of historical figures with some evidence. Newton certainly never took an IQ test.

Comment: @Christi - There are many estimations for Goethe, Einstein etc. They are estimations based on accomplishments, but most of them agree within about a 10 point range.